# Return the value of clicked key button to Sub

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I have prepared a HTA and used VBScript in it.
I have a requirement wherein i have to process certain logic depending upon Button clicked by the user. I have 3 buttons in a form. Now, depending on whether A, B or C is clicked I have to proceed further. Is there way of passing the value of the button to the `Sub` as soon as the button is clicked, so that we can process further with respective logic?

Answer (score 2):

The usual method is to define separate procedures for each button:

```vb
Sub BtnA_Click
  'logic for button A
End Sub

Sub BtnB_Click
  'logic for button B
End Sub

Sub BtnC_Click
  'logic for button C
End Sub
```

and assign them as the `onClick` event handler for the respective button:

```html
<input type="button" id="A" onClick="VBScript:BtnA_Click()" ...>
<input type="button" id="B" onClick="VBScript:BtnB_Click()" ...>
<input type="button" id="C" onClick="VBScript:BtnC_Click()" ...>
```

If your buttons invoke very similar functionality you could make each on-click procedure call a common worker function with a parameter:

```vb
Sub DoWork(param)
  Select param
    Case "A": ...
    Case "B": ...
    ...
  End Select
  ...
End Sub

Sub BtnA_Click
  DoWork "A"
End Sub

Sub BtnB_Click
  DoWork "B"
End Sub
...
```

or you could also have the `onClick` handler call the same function with an individual parameter:

```html
<input type="button" id="A" onClick='VBScript:DoWork("A")' ...>
<input type="button" id="B" onClick='VBScript:DoWork("B")' ...>
...
```

You could even have each button call the same function without parameters:

```html
<input type="button" id="A" onClick="VBScript:DoWork()" ...>
<input type="button" id="B" onClick="VBScript:DoWork()" ...>
...
```

and distinguish the buttons via the id of the [event source element](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/06/05/how-can-i-dynamically-add-controls-to-an-hta.aspx):

```vb
Sub DoWork
  Select window.event.srcelement.id
    Case "A": ...
    Case "B": ...
    ...
  End Select
  ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar Wiechers , it worked perfectly well. :)